# Java API for running UIMA Ruta scripts

Tags: java, uima, ruta

I am new to UIMA Ruta. I made some annotators using scripting language. I am able to run them within EclipseIDE. I want to write a JAVA API to automatically run scripts on the input provided.

I am using the same example project provided in UIMA documentation.

So far i have been able to do this

```
    try {
        File taeDescriptor = null;
        File inputDir = null;

        // Read and validate command line arguments
        boolean validArgs = false;
        if (args.length == 2) {
            taeDescriptor = new File(args[0]);
            inputDir = new File(args[1]);

            validArgs = taeDescriptor.exists()
                    && !taeDescriptor.isDirectory()
                    && inputDir.isDirectory();
        }
        if (!validArgs) {
            printUsageMessage();
        } else {
            // get Resource Specifier from XML file
            XMLInputSource in = new XMLInputSource(taeDescriptor);
            ResourceSpecifier specifier = UIMAFramework.getXMLParser()
                    .parseResourceSpecifier(in);

            // for debugging, output the Resource Specifier
            // System.out.println(specifier);

            // create Analysis Engine
            AnalysisEngine ae = UIMAFramework
                    .produceAnalysisEngine(specifier);

            // create a CAS
            CAS cas = ae.newCAS();

            // get all files in the input directory
            File[] files = inputDir.listFiles();
            if (files == null) {
                System.out.println("No files to process");
            } else {
                // process documents
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    if (!files[i].isDirectory()) {
                        processFile(files[i], ae, cas);
                    }
                }
            }
            ae.destroy();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On running above snippet with default BasicEngine.xml and input text file. It gives below stack trace

```
org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException: Annotator class "org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine" was not found. (Descriptor: file:/D:/uimaOutput/ruta-2.1.0/example-projects/ExampleProject/descriptor/BasicEngine.xml)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:209)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:158)
at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94)
at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62)
at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279)
at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:369)
at org.apache.uima.examples.ExampleApplication.main(ExampleApplication.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at     org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:206)
... 6 more
```

I am stuck. Please help.

EDIT:

**The Java API written above is from uimaj-example from uima documentation. I added some ruta jars and general jars to classpath after which file executed fine.**

Comment: Try finding the JAR with that class and adding it to your CLASSPATH.  Sounds like you're leaning on Eclipse too much without knowing how to do things outside the IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was already solved in the comments of the question. I just want to extend the answer with pointers.

The library ruta-core.jar and its dependencies (antlr-runtime, uima, uimafit, ...) need to be in the classpath of the application. The eclipse plugin ruta-ep-engine.jar contains the dependencies beside uima. For projects built with maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.uima</groupId>
  <artifactId>ruta-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The documentation contains examples on how to call UIMA Ruta scripts from within Java:
https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae.basic
https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.integration

For developers that want to create a command line interface, this class might be interesting:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/uima/ruta/trunk/ruta-ep-ide-ui/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/ruta/ide/launching/RutaLauncher.java

If you are in a UIMA environment (CAS instance is already available), then the method Ruta.apply(CAS cas, String script) can be used for applying some rules on a CAS.

For developers that prefer to use uimaFIT:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/uima/ruta/trunk/ruta-core/src/test/java/org/apache/uima/ruta/engine/UimafitTest.java

Comment: Also to add I referred [this](http://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-2.5.0/tutorials_and_users_guides.pdf) and used ExampleAction.java class for integration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already had a look at the documentation: [Developing Ruta rules and applying them from inside Java code](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae.integration.loading)?